# Getting list of implicitly implemented interfaces for class node

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I work on TypeScript to C# converter.

I wonder if compiler API for TypeScript let me get the list of all the implicitly implemented interfaces for a given ts.ClassDeclaration node.

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    a: number;
}

class ClassThatImplicitlyImplementsISomeInterface {
    a: number = 10;
}
```

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: I think this would require the [type relationship API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9879), but that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidSherret  

At least now I know that I don't waste my time trying to implement it myself, while there is a simple API method hidden somewhere :)